# Woocommerce need to update total count shows next to minicart icon

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, minicart

I'm using riode theme. I need to change the total cart items count shows in the header menu mini cart icon. I've 2 types of products. 1 is weight-based other is normal.
e.g.: My cart items => Product1 - 35gm - $50.00 ;
Product2 -  2(items) -  $30.00 ;
here I need the total cart items to count as 3. but now it shows 37.

Here is my code.

```
<?php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'add_to_cart_fragment',10,1);

function add_to_cart_fragment($fragments){
   
   ob_start();
   $items_count=0;
    
   foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
   $product = $cart_item['data'];
   $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
   $quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];
   if('some conditions'){
       $items_count+=1;
      }else{
       $items_count+=$quantity;
      }
   }
        
?>
    <a class="cart-toggle" href="<?php echo wc_get_cart_url(); ?>"><i class="d-icon-bag">
        <span class="cart-count" style="opacity: 1;"><?php echo $items_count; ?> </span></i>
    </a>

    <?php 
        $fragments['a.cart-toggle'] = ob_get_clean();
        return $fragments;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your code

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'add_to_cart_fragment',10,1);

function add_to_cart_fragment($fragments){
   
   ob_start();
   global $woocommerce;
   $total_items = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count;
        
?>
    <a class="cart-toggle" href="<?php echo wc_get_cart_url(); ?>"><i class="d-icon-bag">
        <span class="cart-count" style="opacity: 1;"><?php echo $total_items; ?> </span></i>
    </a>

    <?php 
        $fragments['a.cart-toggle'] = ob_get_clean();
        return $fragments;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post multiple answers unless you're trying to make two distinct points